# cakephp blog tutorial error whith mysql now()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cookbook

I am triing the blog tutorial from the cookbook

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(50),
body TEXT,
created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

But when I insert the values that he gave me

```
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’The title’, ’This is the post body.’, NOW());
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’A title once again’, ’And the post body follows.’, NOW());
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’Title strikes back’, ’This is really exciting! Not.’, NOW());
```

I get this error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'titleâ€™, â€™This is the post body.â€™, NOW())' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is

```
INSERT INTO posts 
(
title,body,created
)
VALUES 
(
'The title', 'This is the post body.', NOW()
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2796d